# Modded Minecraft Uses Almost All RAM

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-mods

I've been putting together my own collection of 1.7.10 mods for playing Minecraft. Recently, I've noticed it uses almost all of my 13 GB of available RAM, even though it is saying it is using 2-2.5 GBs. My guess is that this is because one of my mods is experiencing a memory leak, causing the ballooning in RAM usage. However, I am having trouble finding a way to learn which, since I don't have enough RAM left to start any other processes once Minecraft is up and running. Also, I can't feasibly solve this with trial and error, since I have 112 mods installed.

My question is, how can I pinpoint the mod that is causing this issue? My constraints are that I cannot use trial-and-error and that I cannot start any processes after Minecraft has fully loaded. That would result in a forking error.

Here's a list of my installed mods, a la Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/5Q7LGhs3

Comment: 112 mods is your problem.  The best way to figure out which one is to disable them, one by one, until your RAM usage drops.

Comment: You say its using 13GB of RAM but saying its only using 2-2.5GB of RAM. That makes no sense to me, how are you tracking these numbers?

Comment: @Frank Packs like TPPI have over 200 mods and only use 2.5 GBs of RAM. Are you sure there isn't any debugger that could show specific threads or classes that are causing me trouble?

Comment: @James Before starting Minecraft, I run `top` in a Terminal session. This shows how much memory is being used total, as well as how much certain programs are using. Minecraft is show to, and tells me that it does, jump between 2 and 3 GBs of RAM. However, once it has fully started up, my RAM usage jumps from 3GBs to nearly 16 GBs.

Comment: You might be able to gain some clues from console output, but ultimately, trial and error may be your only option. Can you post a list of the mods you are using? (pastebin is fine) We might be able to figure something out based on that. Maybe.

Comment: Sure thing: http://pastebin.com/5Q7LGhs3

Comment: So far I've found people reporting memory leaks with this particular version of Minecraft Loader. Try removing that and see what happens. I'll keep poking at the list in the mean time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular version of Minecraft Loader has been reported to cause memory leaks. Remove that mod for now, at least until a new version comes out.